# Is the amount of Mails i am trying to send as a Newsletter somehow connected to the risk of beeing marked as spam or even getting blacklisted?

Tags: php, email

I have a simple Question. I want to send about 400.000 Mails with php on my webserver and its my first attempt to send a Newsletter. I checked my Mail on mail-tester.com and i am getting 9 / 10 Points, which seems to be a pretty good score.

I testes many different Mail Services like gmail. Everywhere i recieve my mail.
But one question remains: Is the amount of Mails i am trying to send somehow connected to the risk of beeing marked as spam or even getting blacklisted?

Thanks for any Anwers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending many Mails from one Server increases the risk of getting blacklisted by some providers, but most hosts of these blacklists wont publish the rules how to get on this blaklist.
I would recomend making a cronjob and sending these mails at 100 per cycle, this reduces the risk of getting black listed.

Comment: Thanks! What interval do you suggest?

Comment: I guess most only compare timestamps so a minute should be enough.